# Ubuntu terminal crashes while installing python package

Tags: python, ubuntu, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to install mmcv python package, but Ubuntu terminal crashes every time during installaction (application simply closes without any errors). I tried to install this package both using standard Linux terminal and via VS Code - the result is always the same. It causes no errors when I install other python packages, but when I try to install mmcv - terminal crushes.

I am using this code for installation:

`pip install mmcv-full==1.3.9 -f https://download.openmmlab.com/mmcv/dist/cu117/torch1.13.1/index.html`

I tried to install mmcv using this code in Kaggle Kernel (it is Jupyter Notebook-like development environment, which works on Linux too) - and package was installed correctly.

It seems to me that my terminal crashes because mmcv is quite "heavy" python package, but I do not know what to do with it. How can I solve this problem and install mmcv?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like my version of Ubuntu is not compatible with old versions of mmcv.

This code worked for me:

```
pip install -U openmim
mim install mmcv-full==1.5.0 -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
```